# Simple task of re-writing of many echo in one. PHP

Tags: php

Please help me re-writing this in a single echo and save it in a variable (`$text`)

```
echo $_POST['var1'];
echo "f";
echo $_POST['var2'];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$text = '';
$text .= 'www.domain.com';
$text .= $_POST['var1'];
$text .= 'f';
$text .= $_POST['var2'];
$text .= $letter1.$letter2;
$text .= '?name=';
$text .= $_POST['var3'];
$text .= '&pass=';
$text .= $_POST['var4'];
$text .= '&id=';
$text .= $_POST['var5'];
echo $text;
```

Comment: Hey thanks! s there a way of creating a 
$text ='www.domain.com'.$_POST['var1'].'f'..........

this is what i am not able to write it correctly

Comment: @JohnQ: yes, you can concatenate all the parts with dot-char `$text = 'www.domain.com'.$_POST['var1'].'f';`

Comment: That dot just annoys me for some reason. It's as if PHP just *had* to do absolutely everything so much differently...

Comment: @Blender: indeed :-) What do you think about \ char as a namespace separator? ;-)))

Comment: Weird namespaces, odd variables (jQuery time), string concatenation, and object classes (`->`? really?) were enough to turn me off from PHP. Python just looks (and develops :P) so much faster...

Comment: @Blender: `Console.WriteLine("Yep");` /me broke the tab button off the Blender's keybord. Try to program now! ;-))

Comment: @zerkms `print '{4} {8} {9} {10} ;)'.format('Oh', 'noes', whatever', 'shall', 'I', 'do', 'if', 'I', 'don\'t', 'use', 'tabs', '?')`

Comment: @Blender with a little experience you'll find that dot very useful

Answer (score 0):

Remember that echo can take multiple arguments (use the comma separator)

```
echo $_POST['var1'] , "f" , $_POST['var2'];
```

You don't need to concatenate.